# Stomp and SockJs in a React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, stomp

Can anyone provide successful implementation of Stomp + SocketJS inside the React Native project? just how to connect it and use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the most important parts:

To connect:

```
connect = (userId) => {
    if (userId) {
      var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:1981/ws");
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

      stompClient.connect({}, this.onConnected, this.onError);

    }
}
```

OnConnected you might subscribe or do it in the first step as you wish!:

```
onConnected = () => {
    console.log("onConnected");
    // Subscribe to the Public Topic
    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/public", this.onMessageReceived);

    // Tell your username to the server
    stompClient.send(
      "/api/chat/addUser/1",
      {},
      JSON.stringify({ sender: "Ali", type: "JOIN" })
    );
}
```

onMessageReceived:

```
onMessageReceived = (payload) => {
    console.log("onMessageReceived");
    var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);
}
```

onError:

```
onError = (error) => {
    this.setState({
      error:
        "Could not connect you to the Chat Room Server. Please refresh this page and try again!",
    });
  };
```

Send message:

```
sendMessage = (msg) => {
    var messageContent = "test"
    if (messageContent && stompClient) {
      var chatMessage = {
        sender: this.state.username,
        content: "Heey there",
        type: "CHAT",
      };
      stompClient.send(
        "/api/chat/sendMessage/1",
        {name: "Ali"},
        JSON.stringify(chatMessage)
      );
    }
  };
```

And you can always go back to the following documentation:
[1]: https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html#subscribe

Comment: how can i handle disconnect event? I tried "stompClient.disconnect = () =>{onDisconnected();};" but it didn't work :(

Comment: When the connection is lost onError will be called. So, you can handle disconnect there.

Comment: Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet
    at SockJS.send (main.js:161:1)
I am getting above error and even can't use clean up function

Comment: how can i wrap the stompClient so that i can use it to send the message on button trigger?