I use stompjs to establish a socket connection, but I cannot execute the logic of the connection establishment callback function
According to the logs of the front-end and back-end, the websocket connection has been successfully established, and heartbeat messages can be seen on both the front-end and back-end. However, the logic in the callback function of the successful websocket connection cannot be executed, the log of the first line of code in the callback function is not output, the back-end does not receive the message sent by the front-end, and the front-end does not have any abnormal logs.
Please help me find out what the reason is, thank you.
The stompjs and react version is as follows
"@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0",
"sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",

The front-end websocket code is as follows
const connect = () => {
        const socket = new SockJS('http://192.168.1.1:5555/ws');
        const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
              console.log('Websocket Connected: ' + frame);              
              stompClient.send("/app", {}, JSON.stringify({message: "Hello from client"}));                  
              
        },function(error){
          console.log(error)
          });
    
        stompClient.onStompError = (frame) => {
            console.error('Broker reported error: ' + frame.headers['message']);
            console.error('Additional details: ' + frame.body);
        };
    };


The console log output in the browser is as follows
Opening Web Socket...
compat-client.ts:35 Web Socket Opened...
compat-client.ts:35 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000


See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297252/stomp-and-sockjs-in-a-react-native
